# Multiple Checkbox selection results

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have 3 color checkbox's Red Green Blue. My goal is to have a user make a selection and show a unique div. E.g. select Red see the .red box. Selecting Red and Green shows the .redgreen box and hides .red and .green etc. There's 8 combinations of the 3 including no-selection (which is default hidden).

I'm open to all suggestions if you know of a more efficient way to get what I need please share. I have made it work somewhat but as I add more combinations the others still show.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    if ($('#red').is(':checked')) $('.red.box').show();
    if ($('#green').is(':checked')) $('.green.box').show();
    if ($('#blue').is(':checked')) $('.blue.box').show();    
       
    if ($('#red').is(':checked') && $('#green').is(':checked')) $('.redgreen.box').show() && $('.red.box, .green.box').hide();
    
});
```

```css
.box {
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.redgreen {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.red {
    background: #ff0000;
}
.green {
    background: #00ff00;
}
.blue {
    background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="red" name="colorCheckbox" value="red">red</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="green" name="colorCheckbox" value="green">green</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="blue" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue">blue</label>
</div>
<div class="red box"><strong>red</strong></div>
<div class="green box"><strong>green</strong></div>
<div class="blue box"><strong>blue</strong></div>

<div class="redgreen box"><strong>red and green</strong></div>
```

Comment: Java != Javascript

Comment: so, what is the problem here? I can't get it...

Comment: Probably best asking this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if your code is working

Comment: My code isn't working. I have it set for 2 combinations but need for 8. I'm not sure how to add more combinations and hide other results especially without repeating multiple spaghetti lines.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal you can use `data` attributes on the `.box` elements which match with the checkboxes which need to be checked in order for the box to be displayed.

You can build an array holding the values checked using `map()` and compare this to an array built from the `data` attributes on the `.box` using `filter()`. You can then display the matching elements.

```js
let $boxes = $('.box');
let $checkboxes = $(':checkbox').on('change', e => {
  let values = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map((i, el) => el.value).get();
  $boxes.hide().filter((i, el) => areArraysEqual($(el).data('filter').split(','), values)).show();
});

let areArraysEqual = (a1, a2) => a1.sort().toString() === a2.sort().toString();
```

```css
.box {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.red { background: #F00; }
.green { background: #0F0; }
.blue { background: #00F; }
.redgreen { background: #FF0; }
.redblue { background: #F0F; }
.greenblue { background: #0FF; }
.redbluegreen { background: #FFF; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="red" name="colorCheckbox" value="red">red</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="green" name="colorCheckbox" value="green">green</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="blue" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue">blue</label>
</div>

<div class="red box" data-filter="red"><strong>red</strong></div>
<div class="green box" data-filter="green"><strong>green</strong></div>
<div class="blue box" data-filter="blue"><strong>blue</strong></div>
<div class="redgreen box" data-filter="red,green"><strong>red and green</strong></div>
<div class="redblue box" data-filter="red,blue"><strong>red and blue</strong></div>
<div class="greenblue box" data-filter="green,blue"><strong>green and blue</strong></div>
<div class="redgreenblue box" data-filter="red,green,blue"><strong>red, green and blue</strong></div>
```

Note that the `areArraysEqual()` logic is the quick and easy version. There are better performing and more accurate patterns to solve that problem. I will leave that as an exercise for the reader if they want to research more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Store your selection in a state variable:

```
const state = [];
If($('#red').is(':checked')) state.push('.red')
If($('#blue').is(':checked')) state.push('.blue')
```

And then combine them to make a selection

```
$(state.join('')).show()
```

You can add if statement to check if state is empty or not and show the default block if so.